# Unity - Swing camera without affecting rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to create a swing for my VR camera but I do not want the rotation of the camera's parent to affect the rotation of the camera.
I have created a Configuration joint on a fixed object connected to the Camera's parent, this joint is configured as follow

[image]

I have tried

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    camera.transform.Rotate(transform.rotation.eulerAngles * -1);

}
```

but for some reason, my camera rotates  360 degrees after half the way of the swing.

[image]

Comment: In the `Awake` function, get the default/starting point of the camera rotation then apply that camera rotation back to the camera in the `Update` function every-frame. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked.

Comment: Sorry, noob here, actually the camera is the google VR camera, hence I cannot fix its rotation, I need to cancel out the rotation from the parent while being able to rotate the camera using the VR gear.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. How can you rotate a VR camera that's being rotated from a Joint component?

Comment: The camera's parent is attached to the Joint, I want to rotate the camera in a way to nullify the rotation of the parent.

Comment: I believe you can get the offset between the camera and the parent object then add to it to the value from my first comment every frame. Maybe that would work....